# Coinwarz API returns broken JSON

Tags: php, json

Using [Coinwarz](https://www.coinwarz.com/) great API for getting coin difficulties for some time. Lately, couldn't parse the returned JSON anymore. I notified their support.

**API call**: https://www.coinwarz.com/v1/api/profitability/?apikey=XXX&algo=all

**The issue**: One of the values had a 'NaN', which prevented json_decode to parse the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The fix**: Add this line to fix returned JSON string before running json_decode!

```
$sValidJson = str_replace("NaN", 0, $sValidJson);
$data = json_decode($sValidJson, true)["Data"];
```